# Pandas ValueError : Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question regarding a transformation I want to add to a Dataframe pandas.
I have a dataframe df with the following columns :

`df.columns =  Index(['S', 'HZ', 'Z', 'Demand'], dtype='object')`

I want to perform the following transformation:

```
for s in range(S):
   for t in range(HZ):
       for z in range(Z):
          df.loc[(df['S'] == s) & (df['HZ'] == t) & (df['Z'] == z), 'Demand'] = D[s][t][z]
```

Where D is a numpy array with the corresponding dimensions. Here is a simple example of what I try to do (with T = 0 for making it simpler).

Here is df before :

```
    S  HZ  Z  Demand
0   0   0  0       0
1   0   0  1       0
2   0   1  0       0
3   0   1  1       0
4   0   2  0       0
5   0   2  1       0
6   1   0  0       0
7   1   0  1       0
8   1   1  0       0
9   1   1  1       0
10  1   2  0       0
11  1   2  1       0
```

Here is D :

```
D = [[[1, 2], 
      [3, 4],
      [5, 6]],
     [[7, 8],
      [9, 10],
      [11, 12]]]
```

And here is what i want:

```
    S  HZ  Z  Demand
0   0   0  0       1
1   0   0  1       2
2   0   1  0       3
3   0   1  1       4
4   0   2  0       5
5   0   2  1       6
6   1   0  0       7
7   1   0  1       8
8   1   1  0       9
9   1   1  1       10
10  1   2  0       11
11  1   2  1       12
```

This code functions, but it is very long, so I tried something else to avoid the for loops :

```
df.loc[df['HZ'] >= T, 'Demand'] = D[df['S']][df['HZ']][df['Z']]
```

Which raises the following error :

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

I am searching what this error means, how to fix it if possible, and if not possible, is there a mean to do what I want without using for loops ?

Thanks by advance

Comment: example of the dataframe and also `D` please:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I added one simple example in the query

Comment: i tried to implement the `for loops` in the question, but it does not work. so i am trying to understand the process of allocating the values in the `demand` column ?!?

Comment: The idea is that I have an array of dimensions S x HZ x Z and a dataframe with columns S, HZ and Z, and I want to apply to each line of the dataframe, which contains a triplet s, h and z, the value of D[s, h, z]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many things, I finally found something that works :

`df.loc[df['HZ'] >= T, 'Demand'] = D[df.loc[df['HZ'] >= T, 'S']][df.loc[df['HZ'] >= T, 'HZ'] - T][df.loc[df['HZ'] >= T, 'Z']]`

The problem is that with this line :
`df.loc[df['HZ'] >= T, 'Demand'] = D[df['S']][df['HZ']][df['Z']]`
I try to access the elements of D with series (`df['S']` for example), which represent columns of the dataframes, and this is not possible. With the solution I found, I access the value of the column I wanted to locate the corresponding element of D.

Comment: It would be great if you could please add an explanation to your answer rather than just a piece of code. We'd like the entire community to be able to benefit from your findings. Feel free to edit your answer.

Comment: I edited my post with some insight, is it good ?

Comment: I'll edit this one for you soon. It's a good start, great job