# How to fill a polars dataframe from a numpy array in python

Tags: python, numpy, python-polars

I am currently working on a dataframe function that assigns values of a numpy array of shape 2 to a given column of a dataframe using the polars library in Python.

I have a dataframe `df` with the following columns : `['HZ', 'FL', 'Q']`. The column `'HZ'`takes values in `[0, EC + H - 1]` and the column `'FL'` takes values in `[1, F]`.

I also have a numpy array `q` of shape `(EC + H, F)`, and I want to assign its values to the column `'Q'` in this way :
if df['HZ'] >= EC, then df['Q'] = q[df['HZ']][df['F'] - 1].

You can find below the pandas instruction that does exactly what I want to do.

`df.loc[df['HZ'] >= EC, 'Q'] = q[df.loc[df['HZ'] >= EC, 'HZ'], df.loc[df['HZ'] >= EC, 'F'] - 1]`

Now I want to do it using polars, and I tried to do it this way:

`df = df.with_columns(pl.when(pl.col('HZ') >= EC).then(q[pl.col('HZ')][pl.col('F') - 1]).otherwise(pl.col('Q')).alias('Q'))`

And I get the following error :

`` IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices ``

I understand that I don't give numpy the good format of indexes to get the corresponding value in the array, but I don't know how to replace it to get the desired behavior.

Thanks by advance

Comment: You'd need to get the actual values out of the dataframe to index the numpy array e.g. `hz, fl = df.filter(pl.col("HZ") >= EC).select(pl.col("HZ"), pl.col("FL") - 1)` then use `q[hz, fl]`

Comment: This instruction seems to return the lines of the array. I tried it and I get the following error : ```TypeError: did not expect value [...]  of type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, maybe disambiguate with pl.lit or pl.col``` where ```[...]``` seems to be a line of my initial numpy array

Comment: Perhaps you could add a code example/test case to make it easier to know what's going on exactly.

Comment: The pandas code does exactly what I want to do. For more details, I opened up a question for the exact same topic in pandas there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73770083/pandas-valueerror-must-have-equal-len-keys-and-value-when-setting-with-an-iter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By test case/example I meant something like:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "HZ": [0, 0, 1, 1], 
    "FL": [0, 1, 2, 3], 
    "Q": [0, 0, 0, 0]
})
q = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])
EC = 1
```

```
>>> df
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ HZ  ┆ FL  ┆ Q   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 0   │
│ 0   ┆ 1   ┆ 0   │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 0   │
│ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 0   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

The problem with your attempted approach is `q[pl.col('HZ')` happens before `.with_columns` executes and numpy does not understand `pl.col('HZ')`

One way to use the actual values to index the numpy array is by using [`.map`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.map.html#polars.map)

```
df.with_columns(Q = 
   pl.when(pl.col("HZ") >= EC)
     .then(
        pl.map(
           ["HZ", pl.col("FL") - 1], 
           lambda cols: q[cols[0], cols[1]])
        .flatten())
     .otherwise(pl.col("Q")))
```

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ HZ  ┆ FL  ┆ Q   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 0   │
│ 0   ┆ 1   ┆ 0   │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 6   │
│ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 7   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

It's slightly awkward to do - it would probably be better to have your data in a better format for polars e.g. another dataframe.

```
df_q = pl.DataFrame(
   ((row, col, value) for (row, col), value in np.ndenumerate(q)),
   schema=["HZ", "FL", "Q"]
)
```

```
>>> df_q
shape: (8, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ HZ  ┆ FL  ┆ Q   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 1   │
│ 0   ┆ 1   ┆ 2   │
│ 0   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   │
│ 0   ┆ 3   ┆ 4   │
│ 1   ┆ 0   ┆ 5   │
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 6   │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 7   │
│ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 8   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

This would allow you to use a more regular approach to matching values such as a `.join`

```
df.join(df_q.with_columns(pl.col("FL") + 1), on=["HZ", "FL"], how="left")
```

```
shape: (4, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────────┐
│ HZ  ┆ FL  ┆ Q   ┆ Q_right │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---     │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64     │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════════╡
│ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ null    │
│ 0   ┆ 1   ┆ 0   ┆ 1       │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 0   ┆ 6       │
│ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 0   ┆ 7       │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────────┘
```

Comment: Oh thanks it seems to do the job ! I think the ```.map()``` function was the missing link in my reasoning. I understand this way of doing is a bit curious but my sata is structured in a way that this kind of operation is necessary for now.